# Неправильный порядок слов в деепричастном обороте?

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, порядок-слов

Я думаю, что некорректно вставлять в начало деепричастного оборота другое слово (не деепричастие).

> Чиркнула спичка, **на секунду** осветив развешенные сети.

Однако не могу найти подтверждение в правилах. Вопрос также возникает при использовании предложений, напоминающих вариант представленный ниже.

> Они, **традиционно** шумя, не заметили, как зашла учительница.

Это предложение, вроде бы, звучит корректно, но напоминает ошибку, о которой я писал выше. Прав ли я?

Comment: Приведенный текст принадлежит перу А. С. Серафимовича, включен в Национальный корпус русского языка. Нет причин сомневаться в его корректности: Чиркнула спичка, на секунду осветив развешанные сети, сено, старика… [А. С. Серафимович. Зарева (1907)]  (http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D7%E8%F0%EA%ED%F3%EB%E0+%F1%EF%E8%F7%EA%E0+%ED%E0). Кстати, сети развешаны (через а).

Answer (score 4):

В начале деепричастного оборота **могут находиться зависимые слова**, например:

― **И ещё раз** осветив хату фонариком, покрутил головой: ― Ну и берлогу ты себе выбрал! ― и уже с улицы крикнул мне: ― Домой подавайся! [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]

Встречные машины, **на мгновение** осветив эту странную процессию, почтительно объезжали их с обеих сторон. [Виктор Доценко. Тридцатого уничтожить! (2000)]

Больше всего правительство не любят сторонники «Яблока», считая его, по всей видимости, чересчур консервативным, и коммунисты, **традиционно расценивая** его как антинародно-либеральное. (2001) // «Известия», 2001.07.09]

Здесь дело в том, что каждое предложение должно иметь корректный порядок слов.

1) **Чиркнула спичка, на секунду осветив развешенные сети.** Нет причин для изменения порядка слов.

2) Они, традиционно шумя, не заметили, как зашла учительница. Само предложение не кажется удачным. Можно написать так: **Традиционно шумя, они не заметили, как зашла учительница.**

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Аналогичная перестановка слов возможна и в причастном обороте?

Comment: Вот пример: Восхищался он легко, закидывал назад голову и показывал крупные зубы, ярко блестевшие на смуглом лице. [И. Г. Эренбург. Оттепель (1953-1955)]

Comment: Jasmin, а КАК все-таки правильно: развешЕнные или развешАнные? "Обсомневалась" вся. В интернете (по запросу) статистика практически 1:1.

Comment: Римуля, сети, должно быть, можно как развесить, так и развешать. "Обсомневалась" не кавычится.

Comment: См. ответ Справки:  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273375

Comment: Значение "в нескольких местах" в глаголе "развесить" передает только приставка РАЗ, а в глаголе "развешать" - приставка РАЗ и суффикс А, то есть это значение подчеркнуто: развешать по городу листовки, развесить  фотографии на стене.  Иногда глаголы заменяют друг друга, а иногда нет.  Интересно, что глагол развесить используется заметно чаще, чем развешать (100:6), а краткое причастие (развешаны/развешены) наоборот (300:80). В наше примере "развешенные" вполне походит, то есть сети просто повесили, где было можно, а не специально развешивали.